# function display live date and time in excel at the same cell. and can add multiple days, hours and minutes taken from other cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

seen in the picture there is a function NOW. how do I write that function so that it can display the live date and time, which is the date and time added from the cell next to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to add the day, but to convert the time to a time by dividing by 24. Dates read 1 as 1 day, so dividing by 24 gives you the decimal for 1 hour.

One note: 1.5 Hours should be written as 1.5, not 1.3 for this to work as expected. Additionally, the time will update with any workbook change event as long as you have formulas updating automatically, otherwise it will stay as it's last value until something is changed.

Here's your formula for cell `L7`:

`= NOW() + M7 + (N7/24)`

Comment: thank you very much it works :D